# Ubuntu touch: collecting data in the background?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gps

I'm trying to implement a simple application for Ubuntu touch which records GPS track in a specific format. Getting the positioning data is straightforward by using QtPositioning, but according to my understanding on the application lifecycle (see for example [here](https://samohtv.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/application-lifecycle-model-policies/)), it's not possible to run such an application in the background, as it will be suspended. Instead of this there are some special services provided by the OS to do activities in the background, for example for downloading or music playing. Unfortunately i couldn't find anything similar for handling position or any sensor data in a similar manner. Is there anything i overlooked here, or there is none? 
If there is none, what is the supported/suggested way to implement such an application?